# How to remove custom top link magento by code

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8

In my module I add a top link by edit layout.xml

```
 <reference name="top.links">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="mymodule">
            <label>mymodule</label>
            <url helper="mymodule/getModuleUrl"/>
            <title>mymodule</title>
            <prepare/>
            <urlParams/>
            <position>10</position>
        </action>
    </reference>
```

How can I remove it by Code ??? please help :D

Comment: Did you manage to remove the links?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the `Mage_Page_Block_Html_Toplinks` class there isn't really a nice, clean method of removing links. A custom extension overwriting this block will be the cleanest solution.

You can read more about overwriting [here on Inchoo blog](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/overriding-magento-blocks-models-helpers-and-controllers/). The overwriting class would look something like this

```
class [Namespace]_[Module]_Block_Page_Html_Toplinks extends Mage_Page_Block_Html_Toplinks
{
    public function removeLinkByInnertext($innerText)
    {
        foreach ($this->_toplinks as &$item)
        {
            if ($innerText == $item['innerText'])
            {
                unset($item);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which would allow you to remove the `My Account` link via layout XML. (You can always do the matching on any other property of the toplinks array like *url* for example.

```
<reference name="top.links">
   <action method="removeLinkByInnertext"><innertext>My Account</innertext><action>
</reference>
```

However. The `checkout` layout file and the `wishlist` layout file use a different approach to adding links. Those can be removed with by adding the following to, for example, your `local.xml`

```
<reference name="top.links">
   <remove name="checkout_cart_link"/>
   <remove name="wishlist_link"/>
</reference>
```